# adding a custom class to the div element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i have a custom component where i am passing some data to render some css styles

like

```
<title :profile="true" :class="true"/>
```

in my component

i have a div as:

```
<div class="tabletitle">
```

i want if my custom class :class is true, i should add a new class called as flexdisplay to it like

```
<div class="tabletitle flexdisplay">
```

what i am missing here, i tried passing the value to data as false but it just throwing random errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your parent component is like

```
<title :profile="true" :showClass="true"/> <!-- modified props name from class to showClass
```

and in your child component, as you said you have a div like below

```
<div class="tabletitle">
```

what you can do is change the above div to the below format

```
<div :class="['tabletitle', {'flexdisplay': enableClass}]"> <!-- where enableClass will be a computed property
```

Inside the script tag of your child component, define props and computed properties like below

```
<script>
export default {
 props: {
  showClass: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false
  },
 }
 computed: { // The reason I am doing with computed is for better reactivity
  enableClass() {
   return this.showClass;
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [class condition syntax](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)

```js
<div :class="{ "active": isActive }"></div>
```

This will put the `active` class if the  `isActive` condition is `true`

*Note* that you can combine the `class` and `:class` attributes to put either class conditionally and classic class

```js
<div class="myClass" :class="{ "active": isActive }"></div>
```

For example in your case if you have the boolean `class` props your component will look like this :

```js
<template>
   <div class="tabletitle" :class={"flexdisplay": isClass}>
      ...
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   props: {
      isClass: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: true
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

**Note**: I've changed the `class` props by `isClass` to better understand and do not confuse with the class keyword

Comment: where this active will go, inj my title component and do i need to declare it in the scrip tags

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, but it is still confusing, what should i pass from the parent component to this class and how  the passing of true and false will add a class or not, reread my question i need to pass something from <title component so it knows what is going on and what has to be included and what not

Comment: Can you update your question and add more clearely what you want to do with an example ? Do you want to pass a class into the props or a boolean that if true will always add the same class ?